# jq - find the name of the array inside JSON object and then get the content of the array

Tags: arrays, json, sorting, select, jq

I have the following JSON array

```
[
    {
        "city": "Seattle",
        "array10": [
            "1",
            "2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "city": "Seattle",
        "array11": [
            "3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "city": "Chicago",
        "array20": [
            "1",
            "2"
        ]
    },
    {
        "city": "Denver",
        "array30": [
            "3"
        ]
    },
    {
        "city": "Reno",
        "array50": [
            "1"
        ]
    }
]
```

My task is the following: for each `"city"` values, which are known, get the names of arrays and for each array, get its contents printed/displayed. Names of cities and arrays are unique, the content of arrays - are not.

The result should look like the following:

```
Now working on Seattle
Seattle has the following arrays: 
array10
array11
Content of the array10
1
2
Content of the array11
3

Now working on Chicago
Chicago has the following arrays: 
array20
Content of the array array20
1
2

Now working on Denver
Denver has the following arrays: 
array30
Content of the array array30
3

Now working on Reno
Denver has the following arrays: 
array50
Content of the array array50
1
```

Now, for each city name (which are provided/known) I can find names of arrays using the following filter (I can put city names in the vars obviously):

```
jq  -r .[] | select ( .name | test("Seattle") ) | del (.name) | keys |@tsv
```

Then assign these names to a bash variable and iterate in the new cycle to get the content of each array.

While I can get what I want with the above, my question - is there a more efficient way to do it with jq?

And the second, related question - if my JSON had the following structure below, would it make my task easier for the speed/efficiency/simplicity standpoint?

```
[
    {
        "name": "Seattle",
        "content": {
            "array10": [
                "1",
                "2"
            ],
            "array11": [
                "3"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Chicago",
        "content": {
            "array20": [
                "1",
                "2"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Denver",
        "content": {
            "array30": [
                "3"
            ]
        }
    },
    {
        "name": "Reno",
        "content": {
            "array50": [
                "1"
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: Which JSON format are you going to decide the 1st or the 2nd version? Which version should the answers be based on?

Comment: @Inian, the one which is the most efficient/simple, but I don't know, that's why I asked about both. I already have my own solution for the 1st version, but if the solution for the 2nd version of JSON would be simpler/easier, then I need to transform the 1st version to the 2nd version first and apply the filter/solution to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the -r command-line option, the following program produces the output as shown below:

```
group_by(.city)[]
| .[0].city as $city
| map(keys_unsorted[] | select(test("^array"))) as $arrays
| "Now working on \($city)",
  "\($city) has the following arrays:",
  $arrays[],
  (.[] | to_entries[] | select(.key | test("^array"))
   | "Content of the \(.key)", .value[])
```

#### Output

```
Now working on Chicago
Chicago has the following arrays:
array20
Content of the array20
1
2
Now working on Denver
Denver has the following arrays:
array30
Content of the array30
3
Now working on Reno
Reno has the following arrays:
array50
Content of the array50
1
Now working on Seattle
Seattle has the following arrays:
array10
array11
Content of the array10
1
2
Content of the array11
3
```